# Different CSS3 transitions for activating and leaving :hover in a DIV?

Tags: css, transform

My question is whether it is possible to have 2 different CSS3 transitions operating on the same DIV?  I'd like to be able to have a rotate and increase in scale on hover (as per the code below) but then when the hover is released for the div to just scale back, without rotating, to its original size.

```
#listitem ul li {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px; 
    padding: 0;
}
#listitem ul li:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1.5); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1.5); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1.5); 
    -o-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1.5); 
    transform: rotate(720deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

It may not be possible due to how to treat the DIV when it is partially rotated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: not possible i'm afraid, not using JUST css :)

Comment: I feared as much!  Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to combine the transitions on `:hover` but your `rotate` is 2 full rotations (`360deg * 2`) so it will be back in the original position. Try changing to `20deg` and you should be able to see the combined rotation and scaling effects. You may have to use JavaScript to keep one transition applied once the element loses the `:hover`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, andyb.  I think I've worded my question badly - the scale and rotate works well on the :hover but I wonder whether I could just have the scale - and not the rotate - when the hover is over.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but as the div rotate with certain angle while hover .. when hover is released it rotated back in opposite rotation and goes back to initial stage.. yes multiple effect can be applied

Comment: only scale not rotation while hover out is not done in css3 transition may be it is applicable with some help of javascript